# CSS: Add Background color only behind text and not entire section

Tags: html, css, colors

I have a text of 2 lines like the following:

```
This is a line
<br>
This is another line
```

And I need to add background color only behind the text

[image: like this].

But only in the back of the letters, not the entire section.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you would need to wrap the text in a span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the element into the ***span*** will fix this issue. Try this:

```
<span style="background-color: black;">
This is a line
<br>
This is another line
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text should be within `<p>` or `<h1>` or something similar. You can add style attributes to that elements (directly or with a separate .css file).
In your case, you need "background-color":

```
<p style="background-color: red;"> Your text here </p>
```

[Here](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/html-color) is a link for more info on text & color.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to 'outline' the text as if it was a stroke and not a background you could use the -webkit-text-stroke element style.

You would first need to wrap the text in a html tag, e.g

or  and apply a class to it.

```
<p class="textOutline">
This is a line
<br>
This is another line
</p>
```

Then apply the webkit-text-stroke style:

```
.textOutline {
webkit-text-stroke: #000;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: medium;
}
```

Be aware this may not work or display differently in older browsers.

You could also apply the background as you have done above ^ and reduce the padding around the element to bring the background closer to the text. This would't appear like a stroke ^ but it would be closer than what you have now.